# Python Selenium Keep Browser Open Receiving New Data

Tags: python, selenium, webserver

I'm trying to keep Selenium browser open and waiting for new information to be passed. I am using a webserver to send url arguments to my computer which triggers a Selenium script to launch a new instance each time. The issue is that the website I'm accessing requires me to login each time I load the site and has a cap of 3 logins every 10 minutes.

Is there a way I can launch selenium browser, keeping the instance open, then passing new arguments through the webserver to utilize the browser instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the login session expiry is the problem then you can use cookies:

you can use this function to save the browser cookies after logging in :

```
import logging 

def save_cookies(driver, store_cookies_file):
    cookies = []
    try:
        cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        with open(store_cookies_file, 'w') as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(cookies))
        print('Cookies saved to JSON file')

    except Exception as e:
        print('Could not save cookies to file')
        logging.exception(e)
    return cookies # return the cookies just in case you want to use them without reading from the saved file
```

later when you want to access the site logged in, you simply load the website, inject the cookies and reload, and you find yourself logged in using your previous session

here's a function to inject the cookies :

```
import logging

def add_login_cookies(driver, cookies):
    try:
        if cookies:
            for cookie in cookies:
                driver.add_cookie(cookie)
                print('Added Cookies')
        else:
            raise ValueError("No Cookies Passed !")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Could not add login cookies")
        logging.exception(e)
```

what you're going to do is this :

```
### SAVING COOKIES 
driver.get('website.url')
....
your code to login
....
cookies = save_cookies(driver, "/path/to/store/cookies.json")

### USING THEM LATER
driver.get('website.url')
add_login_cookies(driver, cookies) # if the cookies varibale isn't accessible, read the cookies from the file you stored them in before
driver.refresh() # or use directly driver.get if you want to access a specific page in the website
```